# pytube error when I try to run a youtube video downloader

Tags: pytube

creating youtube downloader using pytube. but I run into this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/.../Python310/youtube downloader.py", line 4, in

from pytube3 import YouTube

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube3'

script:

import os

import sys

from pytube3 import YouTube

def download_video_with_audio(video_url):

## Get the current working directory

cwd = os.getcwd()

folder_path = os.path.join(cwd, "python310")

## Create the folder if it doesn't exist

if not os.path.exists(folder_path):

os.makedirs(folder_path)

## Get the video and audio streams

yt = YouTube(video_url)

video = yt.streams.filter(only_video=True).first()

audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

## Download the video and audio streams

video.download(folder_path)

audio.download(folder_path)

## Combine the video and audio into a single file

video_file = os.path.join(folder_path, video.default_filename)

audio_file = os.path.join(folder_path, audio.default_filename)

output_file = os.path.join(folder_path, yt.title + ".mp4")

os.system(f"ffmpeg -i '{video_file}' -i '{audio_file}' -c copy '{output_file}'")

## Delete the original video and audio files

os.remove(video_file)

os.remove(audio_file)

## Example usage:

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com"

download_video_with_audio(video_url)

I have installed pytube3 and updated it with "python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip" but it keeps giving the same error. even changed to just pytube but gives the same error. what could I be doing wrong?

need it to download all videos with audio from a youtube channel and store them locally in a folder called youtube downloads. If there can be a 10 video per 5 minute clause in there so that the folder does not fill up too quickly that would be good. format should be high quality